# High-level .NET SDK for reading Saudi Arabia Identity Cards

Tags: c#, smartcard, pcsc, hid-device

I recently developed a C# application that can read the PCSC chip in Emirates Identity card, using the SDK provide by Emirates Identity Authority and HID OMNIKEY 3121 device. But I need to read all the GCC Identity cards that have PCSC chips on them, like Omani and mainly Saudi Arabia.

But all the APIs I found online was low-level, that I have to send byte commands to read data. I even tried to follow some tutorials, but with no luck.

Is there any high-level SDK that I can use to read any PCSC chip card?

Comment: did you got any luck to get sdk for ksa id cards?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what "read an PCSC chip cards" means but basically there are three options with most of the cards:

1. PC/SC API with APDUs - see [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) for .NET wrapper.
2. PKCS#11 API with library provided by the card vendor - see my project [Pkcs11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net) for .NET wrapper.
3. Crypto API on MS Windows with a standalone CSP or at least minidriver provided by the card vendor - supported by .NET natively.

Comment: I have tried your first option, but I couldn't get my code to read data from any Identity card as I'm not good with APDU commands. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write Winscard.dll wrapper.This [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardtransmit#) will help you